# Different return type for the same method

Tags: java, oop

i need to implement the newInstance method in order to make this code to work:

```
protected IDatabase createDatabase() throws Exception{
    return newInstance(CLASS_NAME_DATABASE);
}

protected IDataLoader createDataLoader() throws Exception{
    return newInstance(CLASS_NAME_DATA_LOADER);
}
```

I'm not allowed to touch this code, but when i try to implement the newInstance as Object it means i need to cast the newInstance in the code above you. Is there a way for me to implement newInstance without changing the code?

Thanks!

Comment: use method overloading and type-casting

Comment: What are `CLASS_NAME_DATABASE` and `CLASS_NAME_DATA_LOADER`?  If they're different types you can overload, as Nikos says, and if they're `Class` objects there's a trick you can do with generic methods.  Edit: Also, is `IDatabase` a subinterface of `IDataLoader` by any chance?

Comment: I posted an answer but quickly realized I may have made a mistake in assuming you can overload methods by changing return types; I deleted it again.

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter to `newInstance` were a `Class` object, or something else with a generic type parameter, you could do the following, which would avoid needing to cast the return value, and be type-safe:

```
protected <T> T newInstance(Class<T> klass) throws Exception {
    return klass.newInstance();
}
```

(Note: [`klass.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) is the reflection API method, not the same as the method being defined, despite the same name.)

However, you can use generics no matter what sort of parameters `newInstance` takes:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected <T> T newInstance(String className) throws Exception {
    return (T)Class.forName(className).newInstance();
}
```

This is a bit dirty, because it completely eliminates compile-time error checking on the type of the return value. The compiler will allow `IDataLoader x = newInstance(CLASS_NAME_DATA_LOADER);` but will just as happily allow `int x = newInstance(CLASS_NAME_DATA_LOADER);` (which actually casts it to an `Integer` then unboxes it).

However, manually casting an `Object` return value would also not be checked at compile time, so using generics here is probably still an improvement since it reduces the number of times you have to write each type.

Comment: It might be noted that `klass.newInstance()` is the actual name of the `Class` method. Not the method OP is trying to define.

Comment: @user2651804 Clarified.